# ACF From & To Date Validations

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type 'event' having categories 'conference', 'seminars', and 'meetings' which have a custom field start_date and end_date to define a date for the event.

When one of the Event categories is selected from the right in Admin, a different set of custom fields are displayed as details required for conference/seminar/meetings are different.

I need to validate if the end_date is a date after start_date. Currently, end_date can be entered as a date before the start_date in the Admin.

So, I need to validate the end_date > start_date. I did a search for the code and have it below but not sure why it does not work. Maybe I'm not defining the custom post_type to trigger the validations or even defining event category in the below code.

```
add_action('acf/validate_save_post', 'my_acf_validate_save_post', 10, 0);

function my_acf_validate_save_post()
{


    $start = $_POST['fields']['field_5adb2e8fc30c3'];
   $start = new DateTime($start);

     $end = $_POST['fields']['field_5adb2ea4c30c4'];
    $end = new DateTime($end);



    // check custom $_POST data
        if ($start > $end) {
            acf_add_validation_error('end_date', 'End Date should be greater than or Equal to Start Date');
        }

}
```

When I click on the Update/Publish button when adding a new Event, there is NO alert message to warn - End date should be after the Start date.

How do I need to define to trigger this validation for Event custom post_type and also to show alert in all the three event category (Conference/Seminar/Meetings)?

I'm using ACF ver. 4.4.11.